# Why am I getting build errors (use of undeclared identifier 'methodName' when I try to call it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have defined this method in the .m file:

```
-(void)showHTMLHelp:(NSString *)htmlString pointTo:(UITextField *)textField background:(UIColor *)bgColor  {
```

}

This is it in the .h file:

```
-(void)showHTMLHelp:(NSString *)htmlString pointTo:(UITextField *)textField background:(UIColor *)bgColor;
```

This where I'm trying to call it, but get a **use of undeclared identifier 'showHTMLHelp'**  build error.

```
[showHTMLHelp htmlString:html pointTo:tfShopOpens background:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

As you can see, it IS declared in the .h file, which is imported into the .m file (as normal).  What is causing this?  I have looked at Google and SO (found nothing specific), done multiple Clean's and it won't go away.  I have tried putting 'self' in front like this:  [self.showHTMLHelp] and then I get:

> Property 'showHTMLHelp' not found on object of type 'PreferencesViewController *'

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `showHTMLHelp` is _part of the method name_. It's not an object, but you've written your method call as if it was the receiver.

Comment: Oh... I thought it WAS the receiver... my head hurts!  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea with:

```
[self.showHTMLHelp...
```

You need to first state what object you're calling the method on, and then call the method. You can't use dot notation however. You'll use that for accessing properties. It should look like:

```
[self showHTMLHelp:html pointTo:tfShopOpens background:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

So your method name you are calling is incorrect (you had the parameter name), and you do need to call it on `self`:

```
[self showHTMLHelp:html pointTo:tfShopOpens background:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```